# How large of a file can be played by media player

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am using media player. I want to know that how large of a file can be played in media player.
Please also tell me that what is difference between media element and this media player.
Which is the best to play video file on low bandwidth connection?

Comment: silver-light does media streaming. AFAIK there should not be any such limit.

Comment: but dude m trying to play some large file , and i wait for a long but i didn't play...